# problem using window.location

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have an html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunct()
{
window.location='test.html';
document.getElementById("message")="hello";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="myfunct()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

test.html:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div id="message">Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that `window.location` is working fine but the div is not getting updated to "hello".

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a string to an element, you have to use the `innerHTML` property. Also, as the element is in the page that you open, you have to have the code in that page instead.

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "hello";
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="message">Some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to send the message along from the first page, you have to send it as data to the new page, so that it can display it:

In the first page:

```
window.location.href = 'test.html?hello';
```

In test.html:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = window.location.search.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: The point is test.html already has some text, so when i use window.location to switch to test.html, i want to update the text in test.html

Comment: @user475685: Yes, that's what the code does. The first example above shows that you have to have the code to update the text in the same page where the element is. The second example shows how you can control what text to show from the first page.

Comment: @user475685: My bad, you have to use `window.location.search` to get the query string, not `window.location.hash`. I corrected the code above.

Answer (score 1):

The element you are trying to set to 'Hello World' does not exist on the page you're function is on. You can only access elements on your current page. When a page refresh happens it recreates the HTML DOM from the requested page. You cannot access another pages DOM directly.

Comment: That is not correct. Setting the `window.location` does not immediately load a new page, that happens when you exit from the function and return control to the browser. The rest of the function is still executed.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write

function myfunct()
{
document.getElementById("message")="hello";
}

in test.html page...

and call this function on page Load event of test.html

Comment: The point is test.html already has some text, so when i use window.location to switch to test.html, i want to update the text in test.html

Answer (score 1):

you have to write in test.htm

```
document.getElementById("message")="hello";
```

not in your html

Comment: The point is test.html already has some text, so when i use window.location to switch to test.html, i want to update the text in test.html